# Rules and Facts contradictory descriptions

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Standing to definitions :

A fact is a sentence that states that a relation holds between individuals. A rule is a relation that holds between individuals provided that some other relations hold.

According to this, why it is not possible to
construct contradictory descriptions using facts and rules ?

For example, i can use as facts the fact that a = b and a = not(b) and i have a contradiction....

Comment: A [fact](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/facts/) is a *fact* (a part of teh world) and not a sentence. A rule in logic is not "something that holds between individuals": this is a relation.

Comment: [Tird account of the day ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647254/intended-model-vs-interpretation)

Comment: Im sorry if it's a problem. But im obsessed with knowledge :)

Comment: I do not think. You have made many similar questions in the last few days: at least twelve. Most of them received answers: no vote (up or down), no accept; no requests for clarification; no feed-back at all. *If you are not interested in answers, why ask questions* ?

Comment: A *sentence* expresses a fact, i.e. something that holds or not. In FOL, an *atomic* sentence expresses a relation between *individual*: e.g. $x=x, P(a), R(x,y)$, etc.

Comment: Two *sentences* $\varphi$ and $\lnot \varphi$ are said to be *contradictory*. Thus, e.g., $a=b$ and $\lnot (a = b)$ are contradictory sentences.

Comment: In FOL we negate formulas and **not** "objects", i.e. (individual) variables and constants.

Comment: If i write the rule a(x) <-- not(a(x)) expressed as a definite sentence, this is unsatisfiable. So why using the language of definite programs, it is not possible to construct contradictory descriptions ?

Comment: The *rules* of logic must be *sound*, i.e. they must "transfer the *truth*", i.e. they must produce *true* conclusion from *true* premises. Thus, if the rule is sound and the conclusion is false, there must be some false premise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a fact as an expression that says that some relation holds ... as such you can only express *positive* claims, and not any negations, i.e. you cannot express that some relation does *not* hold. The same is true for the rules: they apparently can only say that some relation holds when other relations holds, and so you cannot make any negations part of rules either. It is therefore impossible to use that $a \not = b$ as a fact, or make that part of a rule. And indeed, without negations you cannot get any contradictions at all.

Comment: This property of rules , is it connected to the fact that we use definite clauses to express rules ?

Comment: @Qwerto Well, it's because by only using positive claims you obtain a system for which you can define very efficient algorithms for checking logical consequence ... I assume this came up in the context of a logic programming course?

Comment: If a rule can say that some relation holds when other relations holds, why cant a rule say something as "if a(fact) so not(a)" ?

Comment: @qwerto if you say $a \not = b$ then you are not saying that some relation holds,but rather that some relation does not hold.

Comment: Maybe i've finally understood: everything we just said about facts and rules rest on the implicit principle that facts and rules are true ? It is that right ?

Answer (score 1):

Who on earth says "A fact is a sentence that states that a relation holds between individuals"?

At least in my neck of the woods, there are two common views about facts -- namely that facts are true propositions (true declarative sentences), or that facts are truth-makers, the sort of thing that makes a true proposition true. But on either view, truth comes into it! A sentence that states that a relation between individuals can be false, and so is neither a fact-qua-true-sentence, nor does it correspond to a fact-qua-truth-maker.

Comment: "Who says...?"  Logical Programmers do.

Comment: Shocked, I am, shocked I say! :)