# Axiom System and facts/rules

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Im studying First Order Logic and im trying to make order of the various concepts.

I think i have understood what is an axiom system (some people call it "Formal System"). But i have two questions:

1) I haven't understood the difference beetween a theory and a formal system. (however i understood the definition of theory)
2) i havent understood how facts and rules are connected to the concepts of formal system and theory.

Can you help me ?

Comment: See the post: [rules-and-facts-contradictory-descriptions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647304/rules-and-facts-contradictory-descriptions).

Comment: In the context of logic a "fact" can be some "ground" proposition having a definite truth value, like e.g. $a=a, a=f(b), P(a,f(b))$, and so on.

Comment: Regarding *rules*, see [Logical programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming): "In all of these languages, rules are written in the form of clauses: $H \leftarrow B_1,\ldots, B_n$ and are read declaratively as logical implications: "if $B_1$ and … and $B_n$, then $H$."

Comment: See also [Facts, rules, goals and queries](http://www.ablmcc.edu.hk/~scy/prolog/pro02.htm).

Comment: If i have a set of facts/rules in FOL, they represent a theory ?

Comment: In Logical programming, we do not speak of "theories".

Comment: Yes, but it's the same thing of definite program ?

Comment: In prolog we add a definite program composed of rules and facts. I dont understand if (for the resolution) a formal system is used or not.

Comment: @Qwerto formal systems have inference rules, that tell you 'if you have this, then you can get that'. They are sort of like rules of chess: they tell you what you can do ... but not what, at any point, you should be doing. Computer programs are quite different: they follow an algorithm that *do* specify what to do next. This is true even for Prolog, as the backtracking mechanism in prolog determines what the next 'move' is going to be. So, I wouldn't call that a formal proof system, but rather an algorithm that works with logic statements.

Comment: My prof. introduced to us an axiom scheme (composed of 5 axioms ) and 2 inference rules

Comment: Regarding *formal systems*, you can see the post [formal-language-vs-first-order-language](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2643325/formal-language-vs-first-order-language).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Theory* in mathematical logic is used with different (but related) meanings.

In a broad sense, we understood as a *theory* in e.g. FOL a set of non-logical axioms on top of the deductive calculus, like [Peano's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) or [Tarski's axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_axioms).

In the first case, we have the so-called *first-order theory of arithmetic*.

It is made of: a (first-order) language, logical axioms (one of many equivalent versions of axioms for predicate calculus), a set of rules (usually, at least *modus ponens*) and the set of specific arithmetical axioms (the first-order version of Peano original axioms).

---

In [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_(mathematical_logic)#Theories_associated_with_a_structure) we call *(complete) theory* associated with a *structure* $A$, denoted: $\text{Th}(A)$:

> the set of all first-order sentences over the *signature* [i.e. language] of $A$ which are satisfied by $A.$

I.e.

> $\text{Th}(A) = \{ \sigma \mid A \vDash \sigma \}$.

A third related meaning is:

> a *theory* is a set of sentences closed under logical implication.

That is, a set of sentences $T$ is a theory iff for any
sentence $σ$ of the language: $T \vDash σ \text { iff } σ ∈ T$.

If we define $\text{Mod}(T)$ to be the class of all models of the set $T$ of sentences, we have that $\text {Th} (\text { Mod}(T))$ is the set of all sentences which are true in all models of $T$. But this is just the set of all sentences logically implied by $T$, or set of consequences of $T$.

For example, first-order theory of arithmetic is the set of consequences of the axioms for arithmetic.

Comment: Good. So, in FOL  i can get a theory by the instantiation of a formal system?

Comment: @Qwerto - now you are using "formal system" in a loose way :-) See the post [axiom-systems-and-formal-systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408131/axiom-systems-and-formal-systems) for a brief characterization of what is a *formal sytem*. We can have formal systems for many applications: one of them is to logic.